# Change styles on fixed element once it leaves default position

Tags: jquery, css

I'm working on a site that is supposed to have a fixed navigation menu, so it scrolls with you. The only problem I'm running into is that the designer wants to make it so once the nav leaves it's position and starts to scroll down the page, it picks up a thick black border at the top. Is there a way to add the style once it starts moving?

Existing code:

```
<ul id="stickyNav">
<li class="technology"><a href="#technology">Technology</a></li>
      <li class="sales"><a href="#sales">Sales</a></li>
      <li class="operations"><a href="#operations">Operations</a></li>
      <li class="marketing"><a href="#marketing">Marketing</a></li>
      <li class="profitability"><a href="#profitability">Profitability</a></li>
</ul>

ul#stickyNav{background: url(../../../images/bb/stickynav-bg.jpg) repeat-x; height: 56px; position: fixed; width: 100%; z-index: 800;}
```

Comment: Please include your current code.

Comment: There is a way, of course.

Comment: Updated to show code - haven't had a chance to try out blint's code yet

Answer (score 1):

There you go some sample to start with, you can check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EhMZ6/) to see it in action!

Note that I had to clone the navigation not to mess up actual DOM. If you navigation has many interactions, you could play with `visibility: hidden` when it starts scrolling.

Good luck!

*CSS*

```
#body {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
}
#content {
    height: 2000px;
}
.nav {
    width: 100%;
    background: black;
    color: white;
}
```

*HTML*

```
<div id="body">
    <h1>Stuff</h1>
    <div id="nav" class="nav">Scroll on the go!</div>
    <div id="content">Interestring things</div>
</div>
```

*jQuery*

```
$(function() {
    var $nav = $("#nav");
    $nav.get(0).originalY = $nav.offset().top;
});
$(document).scroll(function() {
    var $nav = $("#nav");
    var navDOM = $nav.get(0);
    var curY = $(document).scrollTop();

    // Check whether it started scrolling after the navbar
    if (curY > navDOM.originalY) {
        if ($('#nav_clone').length < 1) {
            // Note that you only have to clone the navigation once per scroll event
            $nav.clone()
                .attr('id', 'nav_clone')
                .addClass('nav')
                .css('position', 'fixed')
                .css('top', 0)
                .appendTo("#body");
        }
    }
    // Else, we remove the cloned navigation
    else {
        $('#nav_clone').remove();
    }
});
```

EDIT: note that you can add custom CSS styles to scrolling navbar or original one using appropriate ids `#nav` and `#nav_clone`. `.nav` let you share common styles.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try on blint's code so that may have worked too, but I was given a simpler solution by someone else:

```
sticky = $('#stickyNav');
classtoAdd = 'nav_active';

$(window).scroll(function(){
/* Sticky Nav stuff */
var window_top = $(window).scrollTop();
if(window_top > 0){
sticky.addClass(classtoAdd);


}else{
sticky.removeClass(classtoAdd);

}
/* End Sticky Nav */


});
```

Then I just added any new styles in the CSS as #stickyNav.nav_active{}